# In mysql,For four connection strings , what will be minimum pool size?

Tags: mysql, database-connection, connection-string

what if we set minimum poll size to zero?

And, what will be a default minimum pool size ?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html) the MySQL documentation on connection pooling, this is what it says:

> Most applications only need a thread to have access to a connection
>   when they are actively processing a transaction, which often takes
>   only milliseconds to complete. When not processing a transaction, the
>   connection sits idle. Connection pooling enables the idle connection
>   to be used by some other thread to do useful work.

In your case, if you have 4 connection strings and they all are different (meaning they are connecting to different database server and/or database) then it's safe to say that your application will have at least 4 connections in pool.

Comment: It will mean no connection will be pooled and hence, you will experince delays with db communication in your application.